# Why Python 3.5 uses so much memory? much more than Python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory-management, python-3.4, python-3.5

I've upgraded my Ubuntu to 16.04, and with it Python 3.4 has been upgraded too to new version Python 3.5.

I've ran my python code and I've became numb. It used 1.5x-2x more memory than before. The same code!

The objects counting listing from memory profiler below:

```
=== Python 3.5 ===============================================
                            types |   # objects |   total size
================================= | =========== | ============
                     <class 'dict |        3526 |      2.93 MB
                      <class 'str |       24322 |      2.70 MB
                     <class 'type |        1255 |      1.22 MB
                     <class 'code |        8240 |      1.13 MB
                    <class 'tuple |        3257 |    215.20 KB
                      <class 'set |         566 |    203.81 KB
                     <class 'list |        1356 |    179.02 KB
<class 'builtin_function_or_method|        2356 |    165.66 KB
                  <class 'weakref |        2005 |    156.64 KB
       <class 'wrapper_descriptor |        1278 |     99.84 KB
                      <class 'int |        3488 |     96.62 KB
              function (__init__) |         650 |     86.33 KB
        <class 'method_descriptor |        1212 |     85.22 KB
        <class 'getset_descriptor |        1179 |     82.90 KB
              <class 'abc.ABCMeta |          70 |     66.92 KB

=== Python 3.4 ===============================================
                            types |   # objects |   total size
================================= | =========== | ============
                     <class 'dict |        2306 |      2.12 MB
                      <class 'str |       16819 |      1.90 MB
                     <class 'type |         865 |    824.64 KB
                     <class 'code |        5586 |    785.75 KB
                      <class 'set |         390 |    159.81 KB
                    <class 'tuple |        2206 |    147.46 KB
<class 'builtin_function_or_method|        2170 |    135.62 KB
                  <class 'weakref |        1444 |    112.81 KB
                     <class 'list |         717 |     97.89 KB
       <class 'wrapper_descriptor |        1220 |     95.31 KB
                      <class 'int |        2753 |     75.85 KB
        <class 'method_descriptor |        1067 |     75.02 KB
        <class 'getset_descriptor |         799 |     56.18 KB
              function (__init__) |         399 |     52.99 KB
              <class 'abc.ABCMeta |          46 |     42.16 KB
==============================================================
```

I want to remind - the SAME code gave these different results.

Why it's happened? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you should post the code.

Comment: Also notice that you have a different number of objects in Python 3.4 and 3.5.

Comment: Can you produce a small example script that demonstrates the same difference in memory usage? Given the number of objects involved, I assume your real code is quite large.

Comment: Thanks for an answers, guys.Yes, @chepner, you are right - real code is large. I just thought perhaps someone knows if there is some changes of class imports in new Python 3.5, that may be reason of this unexpectable memory usage.

Comment: @J.Doe, there are two changes you described: One is the upgrade from Python 3.4 to 3.5, and the second change is the core OS upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04. Therefore it may not just be a change in Python 3.5, the change in OS may be an influencing factor here.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It was a memory leak in pycurl or libcurl libraries or both. My app was occupying 2x-3x more memory than before.

When I replaced new versions of these libraries to old, app returned to its previous memory usage.

But indeed Python 3.5 uses +10% memory than Python 3.4 because of new implemented features. It's normal.

Thank.

Comment: I mean "pure python 3.5" without any imports.